# Login jquery não carrega a página após autenticação

Tags: jquery

por favor, esta função não carrega a página. O retorno esta correto, o código entre no laço if, mas não carrega a página que deveria ser o location. O que pode ser?

```js
$('#btnLogin').click(function(){
    var login = $('#inputEmail').val();

    var senha = $('#inputPassword').val();
    
    $.post('_class/login.php',{inputEmail: login, inputPassword: senha}, function(data){
     console.log(data);
      var response = $.trim(data);
          
     if(data === 'OK'){

        location.reload(true);                 
      }else{
       
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
    });
  });
```

obrigado

Comment: Algumas partes do código ainda estão fora da formatação, você poderia editar a pergunta? :D

Comment: faça `console.log(data);` e veja o que imprime

Comment: miguel...já incluí o console.log, mas mesmo assim continua o problema. O código é realizado, retorno a validação do user, não abre a aplicação e ainda retorna o erro. Este erro nem deveria aparecer pq esta no "else"...editei o post com o console.log(data)

Comment: deve estar havendo algum problema na passagem dos parametros usuario e senha, ai o retorno não é idêntico ao que espera o jquery e não faz o if

Comment: Onde vc está usando a var response? Vi que vc faz var response = $.trim(data); e não usa a response. Não seria ela para ser usada no if? Da um console.log(response) e ve o valor que está nela

Comment: andre, não sei pq não consigo ver o consolelog (não sei usar). Fiz o uso do response no if....deu certo...agora que coloquei no servidor de homologação não funciona. Parece que ta quase resolvido

Comment: teste no navegador chrome, com o navegador aberto na página que quer testar aperta ctrl+shift+I, vai abrir o inspecionar elementos, clica na aba "console". Tudo o que vc colocar console.log("alguma coisa") vai aparecer nessa aba console. Se vc deixar no seu código console.log(data) vc vai ver o que está na variavel "data" e vai saber pq não cai no if.

Comment: vlw andre...agora me achei...depois que usei sua sugestão de correção no jquery, meu ambiente de dev funciona perfeitamente. Já no servidor de produção não...pelo console a variável esta trazendo o código da página e não um valor de variável.